# Have there been disputes when software identifies genders with a boolean?

Tags: history

I remember that in our first programming class with Java, while explaining data types, the following occurred (kinda):

> **Professor**: So, what data type would you choose if your program needs
>   to store the user's gender?
>
> **Someone**: How about a boolean? You know, true for male and false for
>   female.
>
> **Professor**: Sure, that may work, but some people may hesitate about that. There
>   have been disputes about calling men "true" and women "false" in the
>   past...
>
> **laughter* *

He ended up recommending us to consider chars (like `'m'` and `'f'`) although booleans should be fine.

I tried searching a bit if there has been any kind of historical entry regarding a major dispute based on this programming practice with no luck.

I'm not asking what data type to use for gender nor if it is fine or not to use booleans. I'm asking if, **historically**, there has been a dispute regarding the usage of booleans to determine the gender in programming because of the apparently "wrong" (I'm not saying it *is* wrong - I don't care about that) behavior of calling a woman "false" as the professor seemed to suggest.

Searching around related questions, the results happen to be only about software efficiency.

Comment: So contact the professor and ask him. Unless he's retired, he should be very easy to find.

Comment: @user16764: I though about that too, but sometimes I have this feeling he was probably joking - so I wanted to confirm it out by searching the web and asking here. It'd get rather awkward if I contacted him and explained to him the whole scenario and then he tells me "dude, chill out, it was just a joke lol" or "I forgot" XD

Comment: As written, that looks more like a pun than a serious description of historical programming conflicts...

Comment: One problem with using a boolean instead of some kind of enum for modeling real world phenomena - one might want to model transgender, XXY chromosomes, etc.  I have seen transgender (2 types) in a real world database as a permissible gender value.  I don't know if it was the result of a dispute.

Comment: As written, I don't see anything that requires the professor's comment to be specifically about software other than the context of picking a data type. I'd say it's more likely that the comment was a reference to non-programming disputes related to gender discrimination.

Comment: What about transgender folks? Shemales need an option.

Comment: @psr: Oh yes, that's another reason he recommended using chars for gender :D

Comment: @PhillipBurch: you can still use a boolean.  Just use "FileNotFound" for the third gender.

Comment: @Omega: Not your professor, but....dude, chill out, it was just a joke. On a more serious note, that represents a bad choice of names not types.  Having the Properties, IsMale and IsFemale with a backing variable _genderIsMale or _genderIsFemale works just fine.  It's all about the name not the type.

Comment: I'm afraid I'll have to close this, your professor made a (bad) joke, this isn't a programming history question.

Comment: @YannisRizos: I find it unpleasant that, as a man, you would close a question that matters a lot to people who don't identify as either male or female, and that could matter to women as well, just because you don't care about it. Especially as it has been upvoted.

Comment: @Niphra If you disagree with the closure, feel free to post a question about it on our [Meta site](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's obvious that it should be `1` for men, `0` for women, because of appearance of reproductive organs ;-P But seriously, boolean does not allow for storing values like "unknown", "not specified" etc.

Comment: @Omega: This is a back-end issue; only the engineers will actually see it.  Cultural concerns usually don't really enter into this.  There are a lot of posts on this topic on http://ux.stackexchange.com/ (e.g., http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/25826/16833 - How can I deal with diverse gender identities in user profiles? )

Comment: Historically, there were no such things as booleans.  There were characters and integers. "M" and "F" would have been way more likely.

Comment: @Brian: Yeah, but I wondered if there were disputes with female engineers or something like that XD. Suppose not :P

Comment: It is clearly a joke, but the joke makes a good point: Don't use a boolean for something which is not a truth-value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more a cultural issue then technical, and represents a society's perspective on gender.

If you studied in an Islamic country or China, then I can understand why this would be an issue.

So the answer is no, I've never heard of such a silly issue in programming.

Comment: To add weight, I work with data from the NHS in England, this is national data covering the whole population. Gender is stored as an int, 1 for male or 2 for female which would raise the same sudo-ethical questions. Here an int is used over a Boolean because other values are used (e.g. unknown, transgender, etc.) but there's no hesitation about using a coding system where it improves efficiency. You wouldn't hesitate about coding other values, so why hesitate here?

Answer (score 23):

Never use a boolean just because there are only two values.  Unless the meaning of true and false will be obvious, use an enumeration if available, and string constants or symbols or whatever if not.  And all too often, there are initially two values and then later there are three.  Or four.

Comment: Very good advice, thank you, but doesn't address the question.

Comment: Which is *are there historical facts about a dispute when using booleans for gender due to the apparently "wrong" moral behavior of calling a woman "false"?* (I realize that the title doesn't include the moral part, but the contents of the question do focus on it)

Comment: There are actually been disputes when using booleans due to the fact people who don't identify as female or male felt ignored or rejected - they were forced to choose a gender (see google+). The use of true/false is less of an issue.

Comment: Considering that most programming languages use a full word to store a boolean anyway, and "gender" is decidedly *not* a true/false property (semantically), then you're absolutely right.  Having a "false" gender isn't a social thing at all, it's just semantically incorrect and you're not even gaining a performance advantage.

Answer (score -4):

Besides the reason given by Kevinn, using boolean in this case forces using variable and property names like isMale (or isFemale), instead of gender.

To me, a neutral name like "gender" is much better than "isblabla" as a property name.